# 1zzfe low engine power

Tags: corolla, power

my 02 Toyota Corolla with a 1zzfe has 240k miles. It runs very well but has low power, especially uphills. What are your suggestions of things to look into? 
I have rebuilt the engine. I am thinking maybe a bad fuel pump or clogged catalytic converter? Thank you !

Comment: Depending on how much you "rebuilt" it may be a bit stiff and lacking power for the first 1000 miles or so, just like a brand new engine. But IMO this is almost impossible to answer. We don't know anything about what you did right or wrong during the rebuild, so it's just a guessing game.

Comment: What do fuel trims do when you go WOT in gear?